# Licensing Model in using Images/Icons

Tags: licensing

I have some doubts regarding the software licensing model.

Recently, while building a small web application, I used some icons/images from iconfinder.com. I filtered icons based on "**Allowed for commercial use(No link required)**". Though icons are listed based on the filtering, still I could see that "*more details*" of those images displays license(s) like - GPL, LGPL, Public Domain, etc.

My doubt is:

1. Can I use those icons/images for commercial user? Because I filtered icons based on "**Allowed for commercial use(No link required)**"
2. My web application is closed source. Do I need to keep the source-code open?
3. As of now my web application do not have credit link in the footer. Do I need to add a credit link in the footer, in case if I have to link back to the website? Is it possible for me to show the credit in the source-page, instead of adding credit links in footer? Will that conflict with the GPL, LGPL, Public Domain, etc licens.
4. Why a licensing model is displayed, if the filter is "**Allowed for commercial use**"?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made the filters as rough filters, which does not represent a single license. Allowed for commercial use simply means it can be used commercially. There might be some requirements such as putting a link to the author's website on the page. Because many developers don't want to put links to a designers page e.g. in an app, I have made a filter that removes those as well. The icons you find with "Allowed for commercial use(No link required)" can be used without linking to the author's website.

I would recommend you read the license for all icons you use from IconFinder.com.

I hope that helps.

Best regards,
Martin LeBlanc